# In Windows, How to know start of application?

Tags: windows

In Windows, How to know that an application is started? I think one way is hook SSDT function. Is there any onther method that does not change windows kernel?

Comment: Use WMI, Win32_Process class, CreationDate property.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4424316/1888362 and search by `APPCERT_CREATION_ALLOWED`