# AppCertDLLs do not work in GUI apps, why?

Tags: winapi, dll, registry, code-injection, createprocess

I was trying to automatically inject a dll to every process (including GUI) whenever it is started by a user . My DLL hooks DoDragDrop method of winapi and communicates with server to decide allow or disallow the drag & drop process. I use easyhook (particularly [this](http://easyhook.github.io/tutorials/nativeremotehook.html) tutorial) for hooking part. I created a gist for my code : [Gist](https://gist.github.com/lapaz17/51d1ccd5b7adb089ce650f0050c5c188)

In [this](https://www.chadduffey.com/2020/06/Windows-Persistence.html) url it says: Doesn’t work reliably against GUI applications. Stick to console apps. No wonder it didn't work in microsoft edge, and chrome.
I also tried code parts in these urls:
[first](https://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/540310)
[second](https://www.cyberforum.ru/win-api/thread304222.html)
Finally , I already [certificated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection) my dll.

Is there any other way apart from appcertdlls? Thank you in advance.

Edit: I can't use appinitdlls, some users might have secure boot enabled.

Edit2: Seems like dlls in some tutorials is under system32 ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354445/appcertdlls-process-creation-slowdown-on-win32-caused-by-virus), and [this](http://rsdn.org/forum/asm/2308423.1)) , and I moved [mine](https://github.com/lapaz17/ss/blob/main/test.png) under system32 too, but it did not
work.

Comment: Why don't you ask the author of the article how they arrived at that conclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine can be used, though it is a solution in kernel mode.